# AdMob rules for using real ads on my own device

Tags: android, admob

Since test ads now work only for English devices, I wonder what happens if I just allow real ads to display on my tablet for a few days or weeks while finishing testing my app. Is this against the rules? Will I get banned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Requesting test ads is recommended when testing your application so you do not request invalid impressions. In addition, you can always count on a test ad being available.

By doing this, you would be loading test ads on your device/emulator.

This is good, since many times, you might tap on the adverts by mistake, and your account could be banned if this happens regularly or if Admobs decides that you are making those taps deliberately to increase your revenue.

Comment: I read that but test ads do not work for non-English language devices, see [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/iJtddcMz2_4).

Comment: If you're testing ricidously then it might be of use switching the device language. You won't be sentenced if you accidentally click it. Make sure you don't try to exploit the system and everything will be fine.